# A bitangent hyperplane to a projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, projective-space, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subset \Bbb P^n$  be a smooth projective curve. A hyperplane $H\subset \Bbb P^n$ is said to be tangent to $X$ at $p$ if $\text{div}(H)(p)\geq 2$. This is equivlaent to the condition that $H$ contains the tangent line to $X$ at $p$. $H$ is said to be bitangent to $X$ if it is tangent to two or more points of $X$. Suppose $H$ is tangent to $p$ and $q$. Then how do we know that $p$ and $q$ have the same tangent line? I can only see that $H$ contains the tangent lines at $p$ and $q$, but I can't see why these two are same. (This is asserted in p.220 of Miranda's book *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*.)

Comment: He's just asserting that the hyperplane $H \cong \mathbb P^{n-1}$ is tangent to $X$ at $p$ and $q$, not that they have the same tangent line.

Comment: @TabesBridges http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2014-15/2term/ma130b/files/AlgCurv-RS-Miranda.pdf But it is written that "it must be the case that $p$ and $q$ have the same tangent line".

Comment: OK, well I don't *think* it's meant to be obvious that these two senses of bitangency are equivalent (indeed, that seems counterintuitive to me). Have you spent much time reading the subsequent proof that bitangents (in the stronger sense) are finite? Perhaps there is a clue contained therein.